# Объединение стринговой переменной и метода

Tags: c#, переменные

Можно ли в C# сделать вызов метода из имени переменной или как-то объединить из. 
К примеру: есть стринговая переменная с именем лэйбла и мне нужно получить одновременно и Name и Text при этом имя этого лэйбла должно приходить как аргумент метода. Я понимаю, что код не рабочий, но хотелось бы что-то в этом духе. Буду рад помощи.

```
public void GetData(string ll)
{
    string keyName = ll.Name;
    string lbT = ll.Text;
    Console.WriteLine(keyName,lbT);
}
```

Comment: [`KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @LLENN можно пример с данной конструкцией? Как это можно сделать с label1 и .Text?

Comment: `public void GetData(Label ll)` ?

Comment: А, кажется понял, что нужно. [Find](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov MSDN не радуют примерами. Как эту радость юзать то? Если мне под параметр Name или Text нужно подставить название label'a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте метод [Find](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find?view=netframework-4.8).

Вместо `this` укажите тот контрол, в котором ищем нужный `Label`. Задайте нужное значение второго параметра.

```
public void GetData(string labelName)
{
    //if (labelName == null)
    //{
    //    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(labelName));
    //}

    var controls = this.Controls.Find(labelName, true);

    //if (controls.Length == 0)
    //{
    //    // не найдено
    //    return; // throw some exception
    //}
    //if (controls.Length > 1)
    //{
    //    // найдено больше одного контрола с таким именем
    //    return; // throw some exception
    //}

    if (controls[0] is Label label)
    {
        string name = label.Name;
        string text = label.Text;
        Debug.WriteLine(name + " " + text);
    }
}
```

В рабочем коде должны быть проверки, наподобие закомментированных. Сообщения об ошибках пишем в лог и предпринимаем прочие необходимые меры.