# Как использовать значение из цикла при обращении к объекту?

Tags: c#, winforms, циклы, for

Есть 39 лейблов с однотипным названием label_1, label_2 ... lavel_39
Как довести до ума этот кусок кода?

```
public void ShowLabels()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i != 39; i++)
        {
            Label lb = 'label_' + i;
            lb.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: *Суть в том, что все эти формы скрыты и их нужно в этом методе все сделать видимыми

Comment: Используйте метод [Find](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find?view=netframework-4.8). Пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/978400/184217

Answer (score 1):

Если лабел уже создан, то к нему надо обращаться через контролы формы(Можно добавить что-нибудь в свойство tag, или определить нужные по тексту .text), допустим, что мы находимся в коде формы, тогда this это форма, тогда:

```
 foreach (Control x in this.Controls)
    {
      if (x is Label)
      {
        ((Label)x).Visible = true;
      }
    }
```

Можно попробовать linq, нет под рукой компилятора, как-то так:

```
this.Controls.OfType<Label>().ToList().ForEach(l => l.Visible = true);
```

Comment: Но на форме есть еще куча лейблов, который названы в другом формате. Я пока еще не понял, как это должно работать

Comment: Я же сказал, либо зайдайте им тэг, либо проверяйте ((Label)x).Text.IndexOf("какой-то текст")>0

Comment: Вариант 2. Унаследуйте класс от лейбла, сделав его class MyLabel:Label

Comment: Всё, кажется дошло, работает как нужно, спасибо

Comment: Хорошо, в дальнейшем присмотритесь к WPF и MVVM, там некоторые архитектурные решения, смогут избавить вас от проблем видимости во View, так-же поняв такую архитектуру, вы сможете строить более изящные приложения.