# Как сохранить данные в txt datagridview c каждой TabPages

Tags: c#

Есть программа имеющая 16 одинаковых вкладок с разным содержанием DatagridView(их тоже 16шт) на каждой из них.

Как сохранить их в цикле за 1н раз в разные txt c названием этих вкладок? Не понимаю что мне перечислять...

```
    TabControl.TabPageCollection pages = tabControl1.TabPages;
            foreach (TabPage page in pages) // Ок, так мы бежим по вкладкам
            {
                SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
                saveFileDialog.Filter = "Текстовый документ (*.txt)|*.txt";

                if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    StreamWriter st = new StreamWriter(saveFileDialog.FileName);

                    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++) итд.// Но что делать тут???
```

Как перейти из вкладки в кладку в цикле ок, ясно. Но как не повторять запись вида datagridview1.2.3.4.5.6.7? Не писать же 16 раз этот код с разным именем таблицы.
 Новичек.

Comment: Можно использовать метод Find. См. [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/978400/184217)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте цикл прохода по списку `Controls` у каждой `TabPage` и если контрол внутри является `DataGridView`, то вытаскивайте данные.

```
foreach (TabPage tab in tabControl1.TabPages)
{
    foreach (Control tabControl in tab.Controls)
    {
        if (tabControl is DataGridView gridView)
        {
            //вытаскиваем данные из gridView
        }
    }
}
```